# Are touch-start and touch-end (i.e. Mouse-down and mouse-up for touch-screens) intuitive?

Tags: usability-testing, touch-screen

I'm contemplating using a *touch-start* gesture (i.e. [Mouse-down](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mousedown/info) for touch-screens) on the tablet version of my website. For what I am trying to do I need to differentiate between a click and a touch-start.

Have there been any studies into the UX of this gesture and *touch-end* also? How intuitive do users find them?

Comment: Not an answer, but I just installed an Android app yesterday that did this, and it confused me for a while.  Worked fine once I grasped it.  It was a video recording/editing app that would record video while you held down the record button... so it started recording on touch-start and stopped on touch-end.  I can see cases where that's sensible, but I don't think that interface will be immediately intuitive for most users.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that touch-end is used on touchscreens to register click events is to allow correction of a miss-touch.  The thought being that the use can drag their finger of the control and it will not activate.  By using touch-start you do not allow users to correct a mis-touched control.

Answer (score 0):

With touchstart you throw away delay in 300ms of click event. 
But touchstart can cause problem with scrolling.

How intuitive it would be for users - i saw more than 500 mobile application, and developers don't implement touchstart for click. This is only my experience.

Comment: I'm not suggesting using it _instead_ of a click. I'm suggesting giving the same element a touchstart property _as well as_ a click property.